# не работает SDL_SetClipboard

Tags: linux, c, sdl2, clipboard

есть код:

```
void sdl() {
    char text[] = "text";
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0) {
        if(SDL_SetClipboardText(text) == 0) {
            printf("work");
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

посмотрел разные реализации так и не нашел что я не сделал что сделали другие. компилирую на linux.
код завершается без ошибки, SDL_init работает.

Comment: код возврата SDL_SetClipboardText проверяли?

Comment: да, вот как раз проверял. как она вообще должна работать? завeршаться и после этого у меня в буффере есть строка или она висит в ожидании нажатия ctrl+v?

Comment: В буфере должна быть строка, которая после ctrl-v будет вставлена куда-то

Comment: Не знаю почему об этом не написано в документации SDL2, но в линуксе для работы буфера обмена процесс, запихнувший данные в буфер, обязан продолжать существовать. Вставка из буфера обмена — это событие, которое процесс обязан обработать, чтобы передать данные получателю. То есть вам нужно не завершать процесс, а вместо этого добавить стандартный SDL2 цикл обработки событий (можно даже ничего не делающий) с `SDL_PollEvent` или чем-то типа того

Comment: в линуксе есть два буфера. И с primary - так оно и есть - процесс должен продолжать держать выделенный текст. Второй (secondary), который обычно через ctrl-c/ctrl-v и работает, этого не требует. Но я в документации не видел на это указаний

Comment: @KoVadim на арчевики писали, что SECONDARY почти никто не использует, а ctrl-c/ctrl-v использует аж третий буфер CLIPBOARD (причём, судя по исходникам, SDL2 пытается его использовать, но, видимо, почему-то не может и переходит на PRIMARY)

Comment: о третьем я не слышал, но в gnome/xfce обычно для clipmanager'ов разных используется второй, плюс очень часто они делают "синхронизацию буферов

Comment: я бы в код выше добавил цикл обработки событий и посмотрел, будет ли работать. Но подымать целый sdl для буфера - как то перебор.

Comment: @KoVadim думаю, под «вторым» обычно имеют в виду этот самый CLIPBOARD

Comment: @andreymal у меня как раз была такая функция которая ждала нажатия клавиши и все равно ничего не вставлялось пробовал как и перед sdl_qiut так и после. так же попробовал sdl_pool_event программа не зваершается но и в буффере так же ничего нет

Comment: @panthamima нужно не ждать нажатия клавиши, а обрабатывать входящие события через SDL_PollEvent. Когда я попробовал, у меня всё заработало, как конкретно вы пробовали?

Comment: @andreymal SDL_Event event;  SDL_PollEvent(&event);

Comment: @panthamima а надо это в цикле повторять, обрабатывая абсолютно все поступающие события, а не только самое первое. Ведь совсем не факт, что событие вставки из буфера обмена окажется первым и единственным

Comment: @andreymal все, заработало. но не сможете подсказать как например сделать ивент который завершается после нажатия ctrl+v?

Comment: @panthamima похоже, это трудно. SDL2 не отдаёт наружу никаких событий про буфер обмена, придётся включить получение системных событий `SDL_EventState(SDL_SYSWMEVENT, SDL_ENABLE);` ждать появления X11 событий `if (e.syswm.msg->subsystem == SDL_SYSWM_X11) {` и потом в нём отслеживать появление запроса содержимого `if (e.syswm.msg->msg.x11.event.type == SelectionRequest) {`. Но это всё только X11, а если вспомнить ещё про Wayland и другие операционные системы, то наверное уже проще застрелиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

простейший пример с SDL_PollEvent, который обрабатывает все event в том числе и буффер обмена. все заработало спасибо @andreymal

```
void sdl() {
    char text[] = "text";
    SDL_Event event;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0) {
        if(SDL_SetClipboardText(text) == 0) {
            while(1) {
                SDL_PollEvent(&event);
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Если в цикле больше ничего не происходит, то наверное вместо `SDL_PollEvent` лучше взять `SDL_WaitEvent`, он будет дожидаться следующего события и не жрать проц вечным циклом вхолостую